# edit layer in silverlight code behind esri map

Tags: silverlight, esri

I want change layer user able to edit layer:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfWMZ.png)

```
                        <esri:GraphicsLayer ShowLegend="false" ID="ResultsGraphicsLayer" />
                        <esri:GraphicsLayer ShowLegend="false" ID="MyGraphicsLayer" />
                        <esri:GraphicsLayer ShowLegend="false" ID="MySelectionGraphicsLayer" MouseEnter="GraphicsLayer_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="GraphicsLayer_MouseLeave"/>
                        <esri:GraphicsLayer ShowLegend="false" ID="IdentifyIconGraphicsLayer"/>

                    </esri:Map>
```

Comment: You may want to re-translate your question. It's not clear what you're asking sorry.

Comment: I want to add ShapeFile in esri Map in Silverlight